# Different results in Clang and GCC when casting to std::optional<T>

Tags: c++, g++, option-type, c++17, clang++

Given the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

struct foo
{
    explicit operator std::optional<int>() {
        return std::optional<int>( 1 );
    }
    explicit operator int() {
        return 0;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo my_foo;
    std::optional<int> my_opt( my_foo );
    std::cout << "value: " << my_opt.value() << std::endl;
}
```

[gcc 7.2.0 writes](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yXd0odQ6W2oUrpUj) `value: 1`.

MSVC 2017 (15.3) and [clang 4.0.0 however write](https://wandbox.org/permlink/StVsiuAJky5OLZML) `value: 0`.

Which one is correct according to the C++ standard?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since this is direct-initialization, we [enumerate the constructors](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.6.2) and just pick the best one. The relevant constructors for [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) are :

```
constexpr optional( const optional& other ); // (2)
constexpr optional( optional&& other ) noexcept(/* see below */); // (3)

template < class U = value_type >
/* EXPLICIT */ constexpr optional( U&& value ); // (8), with U = foo&
```

Both are viable (`(8)` only participates in overload resolution if `int` is constructible from `foo&` and `foo` is neither `std::in_place_t` nor `std::optional<int>`, all of which hold), but `(8)` is an exact match whereas `(2)` and `(3)` require a user-defined conversion, so it should be preferred. gcc is wrong here.

However, gcc doesn't actually invoke `(3)` either. It just directly initializes `my_opt` from the result of converting `my_foo` to an `optional<int>`. This program with gcc 7.2 prints `3` but none of  `1a`, `1b`, or `2`:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct opt {
    opt() { }
    opt(opt const& ) { std::cout << "1a\n"; }
    opt(opt&& ) { std::cout << "1b\n"; }

    template <class U>
    opt(U&& ) { std::cout << "2\n"; }
};

struct foo 
{
    explicit operator opt<int>() { std::cout << "3\n"; return {}; }
};

int main()
{
    opt<int> o(foo{});
}
```

I don't think that's an allowable route. I filed [81952](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=81952).

Comment: I always thought that overload resolution preferred non-templates. Why is it different here?

Comment: @Rakete1111 It's not different here. Overload resolution does not "always" prefer non-templates. Given two candidates that have equivalent conversion sequence rankings, one of the tiebreakers is then to prefer the non-template. But we don't have equivalent conversion sequence rankings here.

Comment: @Barry Don't we have two conversions with the same ranking? One to `int`, which would take (8) and one for `optional<int>`, which would take (2)?

Comment: @Rakete1111 No, there's no conversion for `(8)`. The conversion to `int` happens inside the constructor itself.

Comment: This is very likely to be another bug with GCC's P0135 implementation.

Comment: @T.C. Filed a bug. It's odd, since I think that's probably what we want to happen - even if it's not allowed to happen.

Comment: @T.C. what is the GCC P0135 implementation?

Comment: @Downvoter Reasoning? I'm fairly sure this is correct, and the gcc bug just got moved to NEW status.

Comment: @Barry Sorry, I guess I do not understand your answer fully yet. Is clang correct with its output (`0`) according to the standard? I would expect something different. But I guess it would not really fit into this thread, so I just opened [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45861479/why-is-a-cast-operator-to-stdoptional-ignored).